# Why am I getting 'Objects are not valid as a React child' error even though I am not rendering anything?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

So I have a function called onHideUnderlay. It's basically just a payload builder to dispatch an action, but somehow I'm getting this error.
This is the function:

```
addItemToCart = () => {
    let thisPayload = {};
    thisPayload.cartCount=this.props.cartCount+1;
    let existingContent=this.props.cartContent;
    let itemToAdd = {};
    itemToAdd.title=this.props.currentPickedMenuItem.title;
    itemToAdd.description=this.props.currentPickedMenuItem.description;
    existingContent.push(itemToAdd);
    thisPayload.cartContent=existingContent;
    store.dispatch(addItemToCart(thisPayload));
}
```

This is the JSX.

```
<TouchableHighlight
  style={styles.cartButton}
  activeOpacity={0.5}
  onPress={() => {
    return true;
  }}
  underlayColor={"forestgreen"}
  onHideUnderlay={this.addItemToCart}
>
  <View style={styles.cartActualButton}>
    <Text style={styles.cabText}>ADD TO CART</Text>
    <Icon
      size={30}
      style={styles.cabIcon}
      name="cart-plus"
      type="font-awesome"
      color="white"
    ></Icon>
    <Text style={styles.cartCount}>({this.props.cartCount})</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't be sure without seeing the data, but it's likely coming from ```this.props.cartCount```.  Doublecheck and make sure that it's a string.  Looks like you're setting ```thisPayload.cartCount``` to an array? If you're updating ```cartCount``` from a number to an Array, that error will occur when React tries to render it.

Comment: You are rendering in `<Text>` tag like Rutherford says, check the value of `this.props.cartCount`

Comment: Thank you guys, yes, it was just a datatype issue. I was settting it to an array instead of a string.